# Map JSON-pointer to the {line, column} in a text JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, source-maps, jsonpointer

I need to map a location in JSON (or JavaScript object) defined by JSON-pointer to the position in JSON text file as `{line,column}`. Is there any existing JavaScript library that would do it? Writing this code is going to be a bit tedious...

For example, if I have a JSON file (text):

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

then given JSON-pointer `/foo/0/bar` I need to get `{line: 4, column: 7}` as the result.

If an equivalent JSON value is stored in this JSON file:

```
{"foo":[{"bar":1}]}
```

then the result for the same JSON pointer should be `{line: 1, column: 10}`.

Comment: If it's okay to only handle specifically formatted JSON, you can push the problem back to doing a clone of the JSON, generate some guid, put the guid in that path and stringify, use string searching for the guid

Comment: It won't work, as path can point to a scalar value (like in example) and there is no way to add some UUID to this value. You can add it to a parent object, but I need to map all paths. You can of course replace scalar values with some arrays/objects, but then it would change positions in the original file below (even if it's specifically formatted)... Also, ideally I need mappings to original source files, rather than in specifically formatted JSON.

Comment: Seems like you will need to write a customer parser/interpreter. Either see if you can build on an existing JSON implementation or start writing your own http://jsbin.com/xixuyiwiwi/edit?js,output

Comment: I've done the opposite task so far: generate mappings while stringifying. https://github.com/epoberezkin/json-source-map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This library has the equivalents of JSON.parse/stringify that also return mappings: https://github.com/epoberezkin/json-source-map